# "classList.toggle" doesn't apply styles, but it gets applied manually

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I've been creating a night mode for my web page and made a specific class in CSS to apply when it toggles. However it applies to some elements but not for some. But when I write code for each element without classList.toggle it works. I can't figure out what goes wrong. I don't even get errors in console also. I'd really appreciate if you could help me. Thank You.

HTML:

```
<body id="body">
<div class="top-right">
    <button id="nightMode">Night Mode</button>
</div>
<header>
    <h2>PHOTOGRAPHER</h2>
    <h1>Kylo Ren</h1>
</header>

<section class="pricing" id="price">
    <div class="price-section">
        <div class="price-card">
            <div id="head">
                <h3 class="title">Basic</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="price-sub">
                <div class="sub-sec">
                <h3>100+ Photos</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-sec">
                    <h3>BnW Editing</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-sec">
                    <h3>Soft Copy</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-sec" id="foot">
                    <h3>$499</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer id="footer">
    <h4>Powered By Kisara Fernando</h4>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
   .darkTheme{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.lightTheme{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

JS:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('nightMode');
let footer = document.getElementById('footer');

btn.addEventListener('click' , changeBg);

function dark(){
    btn.classList.toggle("lightTheme");
    body.classList.toggle("darkTheme");
    footer.classList.toggle("lightTheme");  
    
    document.querySelectorAll('#head')[0].classList.toggle("darkTheme");
    document.querySelectorAll('#head')[1].classList.toggle("darkTheme");
    document.querySelectorAll('#head')[2].classList.toggle("darkTheme");
}


function changeBg(){
    dark();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of your element starts with `lightTheme` set. Every time you click the button, your button and footer will add/remove the lightTheme (but never the darkTheme), and your body will add/remove the darkTheme.

A solution could be just toggle the darkTheme to both the button and the body (the footer will update with the body):

```
btn.classList.toggle("darkTheme");
body.classList.toggle("darkTheme");
```

**Note:** Your lightTheme class would be completely useless here.

Comment: I don't get it but lightTheme Worked for the footer. It doesn't work with button and the <div id="head">. That's the problem